# Git commit list of the current branch with libgit2sharp

Tags: libgit2sharp

Is there a way with libgit2sharp to get the list of commits which are on the current branch I am on?

Like I guess it is done with Github in a Pull Request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To retrieve the current branch:

```
var branch = repo.Head;
```

To retrieve the list of commits reachable from this branch:

```
var commits = branch.Commits;
```

To retrieve the list of commits that have been introduced in this branch and are not known (ie. reachable) by another branch (eg. the base branch of a Pull Request):

```
var newCommitsThatMasterDoesNotKnowAbout = repo
     .Commits
     .QueryBy(new CommitFilter { Since = branch, Until = repo.Branches["master"] });
```

Comment: If I don't want to have to specify the base branch, e.g "master", is there a way?

Comment: Not in git. You need something to compare against. `git log HEAD` will list all the reachable commits from HEAD. `git log master...HEAD` will only output the one that master doesn't know about.

Comment: Yeah that's right I just realized that when you create a Pull Request you specify both, so that's it.

Comment: If that answer provided you with any help, maybe could you consider accepting/upvoting it? ;-)

Comment: For sure I will when I find time to test the answer ;)